# Making a Google Maps demo work with Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, webkit, drag

[This](http://www.johnmick.net/drag-div-v3/) is a demo of dragging on Google Maps v3,

It doesn't work well in Google-Chrome or Safari --

what do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: I'd be looking at using the maps API to handle the dragging, rather than jquery ui. It appears custom overlays can't be draggable, but markers can. The issue here I suppose is that you're using a div rather than an icon, so making this as a custom marker mightn't be the best solution for you as I think markers are limited to being images (I could be wrong here). I'm interested to see what people suggest here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is ok now:

```
.bind('mouseenter',function(){
                map.setOptions({
                    draggable:false
                })
            })
            .bind('mouseleave',function(){
                map.setOptions({
                    draggable:true
                })
            })
```